# Kafka Connect can't find ZoneRulesProvider after adding db.timezone property

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, java-time

I'm running Kafka Connect (Confluent) in distributed mode, and have recently added the db.timezone property to my JDBC Source Connector. After doing so I'm seeing this error when I load the connector:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider\n\tat java.time.ZoneRegion.ofId(ZoneRegion.java:120)\n\tat java.time.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:411)

This is happening from this code in JDBCSourceConnectorConfig:

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/jdbc/source/JdbcSourceConnectorConfig.java#L807

If I log into my Kafka Connect box and run `java -version` I get:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_262"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_262-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.262-b10, mixed mode)
```

If I create a small Java Program like the following and run it on that box, it works fine:

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class TestTime {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dbTimeZone = "America/New_York";
    System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId.of(dbTimeZone)));
    System.out.println(ZoneRulesProvider.getAvailableZoneIds());
  }
}
```

So why is confluent/kafka connect breaking on it? Why would it not be able to find `ZoneRulesProvider`?

Answer (score 0):

After doing a restart of kafka connect on my servers this issue appears to have gone away.